# Running react-native app on iOS device using offline bundle

Tags: react-native

The official [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#using-the-offline-bundle) documentation to run app on iOS device using offline bundle says

> Open ios/YourApp/AppDelegate.m
>
> Uncomment the line, jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] ...

Using latest `react-native 0.30.0`, this line is no longer present in the default `AppDelegate.m` file. Excerpt from the default `AppDelegate.m` file

```c
NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                    moduleName:@"TestAppDelete"
                                             initialProperties:nil
                                                 launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

If I try to use the `jsCodeLocation` as it used to be in previous versions, it is returned as null

```c
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

I am not sure why is the URL for `main.jsbundle` returned as `null`. Is it not created by the packager anymore. If it should be created using the latest version also, how can I confirm it?

If you have run a `react-native 0.30.0` app on an iOS device using offline bundle, please share the instructions to do so.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**EDIT**: The whole bundle ip detection should be automatic on the latest release of react-native. If you select your device on xcode do `build and run` and run the app once. It should save an offline bundle on the phone so that if it doesn't find a packager server running, it will use the offline bundle.

source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/8c29a52c54392ce52148e7d3aa9f835537453aa4

---

If you change to a `release` scheme while building your app, that will compile your app with the offline bundle.

Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > set `build configuration` to `Release`.

Not sure why they didn't update the documentation for the `Appdelegate.m` method. Looks like the line is still there on the sources. [Edit: there's a [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/65ff8192dd6a542485d1ea0647eadee44d76a55b) for this]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. This change was not mentioned in the release notes and since I have changed the `AppDelegate` file in my app, I just replaced it after `react-native` upgrade and the documentation wasn't updated either which confused things further. Just a note - If I run the app on the device without changing the `Build Configuration` to `Release`, then I was able to run the app as long it was connected to the mac. If I stop the app, disconnect the phone and try to run it again, it doesn't start. Setting the `Build Configuration` to `Release` helped in that case. Thanks again!

Comment: I hope I could upvote the answer multiple times :). I just spent too much time yesterday to figure it out.

Comment: Cheers, man! Was it not for your answer, I wouldn't have known myself. :) I haven't tried it out, but saw it on the sources. Will update once I try it out.

Comment: Once changing to release version I am no longer able to debug my app using the react native debugger.. Also the build time takes ages. Is this the only solution to this? Can I somehow solve this and keep running in debug mode? Thanks

Comment: Changing to a Release configuration solves only half the problem. Release builds don't allow debugging, which kind of leaves us flying blind.

Comment: **Not a solution** -  to develop using **release builds**.  I did try it however it did not work for me.  The only fix I could get to work on react native 0.37 was to go back to the "old school" method of manually editing jsCodeLocation in AppDelegate.m. Debugging is good again!

Comment: @EdoftheMountain We fixed it without changing the scheme to a release version, check out what we did here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40730709/1438478

Answer (score 13):

When I open the global proxy in ShadowsocksX, automatic IP detection won't return `http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle` in the debug mode.
That's why the URL for main.jsbundle returned as `null`.

**How to solve?**

Option 1:

replace

```c
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
```

with

```c
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

This method could disable automatic IP detection.

Option 2:

Switch your proxy mode if you open the global proxy mode.

Comment: Option 1 doesn't work anymore with latest react-native

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr Make sure your localhost ip address is explicitly stated in your hosts file, and that your hosts file hasn't become corrupted.

So our team kept hitting this issue. It turns out that React Native reads the host file on your machine looking for the URL to store, so that it can pull the js to create an offline bundle, or to just reach the packager while the app is running on your device.

We actually weren't trying to run this as an offline bundle, just in the ios simulator, so we were left really scratching our heads. We found the fix because the needed fix was also causing other issues with react native. Our etc/hosts file on a mac didn't have the localhost ip explicitly stated. I added that in and the problem seemed to go away. Forgive me as I don't know much about osx and dns resolution but it seems that with the new automatic ip detection, this is now necessary.

I am not sure how react native is getting the ip, if it is reading the hosts file, or the host file is propogating something else in osx that rn is reading, but if the above fix doesnt work for you, I would look to see if the hosts file itself is corrupted with certain characters that cause it not to be read. In my hunting for the solution to this problem, I came across many posts and questions about malformed hosts files that caused issues with localhost being resolved properly.

Also, it seems there is an effort underway to update the ip detection, but I am not well versed enough in obj c to know if this issue would be corrected by the new code. Maybe someone can take a look? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/8789

Another also, clearing your osx DNS cache may help https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/clear-the-local-dns-cache-in-osx/

Comment: +1 .. Awesome research! I only had this issue with certain routers. (I move around a lot). But the line for pointing in hosts had been commented out.

Putting 
127.0.0.1 localhost
into my hosts file fixed the problem! Thank you so much! I was searching for hours for a fix.

Answer (score 2):

The only fix I could get to work on **react native 0.37** was to go back to the "old school" method of manually editing **jsCodeLocation** in **AppDelegate.m**.  Debugging is good again!

Be sure your device and development machine are on the same wi-fi, and maybe disconnect any wired Ethernet until you get it working.

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  // Comment-out, cannot get past error: bundleURL must be non-nil when not implementing loadSourceForBridge
  //jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

#if DEBUG
  NSLog(@"AppDelegate:DEBUG");

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
  NSLog(@"AppDelegate:DEBUG:TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR");
  jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];
#else
  NSLog(@"AppDelegate:DEBUG:!TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR");
  NSLog(@"To device debug, open RCTWebSocketExecutor.m & replace localhost with MacBook IP.");
  // Get dev host IP Address:
  //    ifconfig | grep inet\ | tail -1 | cut -d " " -f 2
  jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.16.29.213:8081/index.ios.bundle"];
#endif

#else
  NSLog(@"AppDelegate:RELEASE jsbundle");
  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif

  NSLog(@"jsCodeLocation = %@",jsCodeLocation);


  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"BluetoothConnect"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that I had fiddled with the Info.plist and removed the localhost app transport security exception.  Adding this back into Info.plist fixed it for me:

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<!--See http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/ -->
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would make sure I have `ios-deploy` installed.

You can do so by running `npm install -g ios-deploy`

Then connect the iphone you want the app to be installed in into your mac.

Then run

```sh
react-native run-ios --device "ABC’s iPhone" --configuration=release
```

This would create a offline js bundled app and install it onto the iphone.

*PS: If it errors out saying*

```
Signing for "<app name>" requires a development team. 
Select a development team in the project editor.
```

Then open up the project inside `ios/` in Xcode and 
Select the target -> General Tab
Under signing choose the signing team and choose automatically manage signing.

Then save and re-run the command.