# Why I should edit the Info.plist and AppDelegate files before creating the IPA in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store-connect, application-loader

I was reading in a guide that I need to change the Info.plist and AppDelegate.m files before publishing my react-native app to iOS with Xcode.

Is it necessary to change the Info.plist file by deleting this code:

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

and by changing in AppDelegate.m this line:

```
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
```

to this line:

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

Can someone please explain why should I do that?

Comment: Hey! Please refer to here for your question. As far as I know, detection is automatic when you build your project and manual update is not necessary https://stackoverflow.com/a/38780622/9890122

Comment: @Harrison manual update can make my app to fail? in case that I already succeeded to archived the app and send it to iTunes connect with no error

Comment: In that case you're good to go congratulations!

Comment: @Harrison just want to make sure I understand when I upload my app to iTunes connect and it says upload successful it means that the app will work, I mean during the upload they like "testing" the app and making sure its not crash?

Comment: I assume when you say that you've uploaded your app for review by Apple means that you've already tested your app in both a debug and user environment right? So if you've tested your app yourself for your target user audience then yes Apple should have no problems testing your app.

Comment: @Harrison only test on debug mode and still waiting to get the links through the testFlight.. theres another way to test it?

Comment: yes, as long as you've tested it on a physical device. Please check this page and see if you've performed all the actions that are recommended there: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device

Comment: @Harrison yes I did it, and right now I changed to release mode and run it on physical device with no problem... thank you!